# Iterator on IndexedSeqLike fails to be an Iterator

Tags: scala

The following code doesn't work with Iterator semantics

```
val a = 1.to(10).toIterator
println(a.take(10).toList)
println(a.take(10).toList)
```

The general expectation on any iterator is that first one should give 10 items but the next one should be empty. The List's toIterator works as expected though

```
val a = 1.to(10).toList.toIterator
println(a.take(10).toList)
println(a.take(10).toList)
```

Apparently the bug is because of overriding the take and drop in the Elements in here https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqLike.scala

We either should not implement Iterator for Elements or not override take/drop/slice in it.

Or is it intentionally behaving that way?

Comment: According to the docs of the iterator trait, behavior of the iterator after calling method take on it is undefined. I think behavior you encountered can be classified as "undefined".